# Find $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$ such that $\phi_1 + \phi_2 = \psi$

Tags: rotations, quantum-mechanics, symmetry, projection-matrices

I have a function $\psi(x,y)$ which I have found by numerically minimising the energy of a Hamiltonian.

The problem is that there are multiple functions (let's say $2$ in this case for the sake of simplicity) that have the same energy. The way the code works, this $\psi$ is the *sum* of all degenerate functions:
$$ \psi(x,y) = \phi_1(x,y) + \phi_2(x,y).$$

My question is: can I somehow extract $\phi_1$ and/or $\phi_2$ from $\psi$ purely form mathematical manipulation? I.e. not through perturbation theory.

I can guess some relationship between the two functions: e.g. that one if the $\pi/2$ rotation of the other. In which case I can rewrite this as:
$$ \psi(\mathbf{r}) = \phi_1(\mathbf{r})+\phi_1(R^{\pi/2}\mathbf{r}).$$

Can I solve this particular case to find $\phi_1$?

Comment: Do you mean that you *know* the Hamiltonian is invariant under $\pi/2$ rotation (or reflection)?

Comment: No. I just know there’s a rotational symmetry so that was a good starting guess.

Comment: I’m basically trying to see what would/could work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is $\psi(y,x)$ also minimal?

Comment: yes. $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are degenerate energy eigenstates with the same $E$. But my code just returns the "pre-factor" to the energy $E$ term, so it returns the sum of all the degenerate eigenstates $\psi(x,y) = \phi_1(x,y) + \phi_2(x,y)$. $\psi$ is hence also an eigenstate with energy $E$. I am trying to see whether there's any tricks I can try to "break" this degeneracy, without perturbation theory.

Comment: For example, in the 2D harmonic oscillator, there is nothing special about  degenerate eigenstates oriented with the axes, or at any angle. Do you just want any orthogonal pair $\phi_1, \phi_2$ ?

Comment: Well those eingestats give me the energy $E$ that I am looking for when I apply the Hamiltonian.